# Guzzle Laravel - Login using POST request

Tags: php, json, laravel

What I am trying to do is to login to an external API and retrieve a JSON file. For this I am using Guzzle in Laravel.

I have setup a controller to do this:

```
   $client = new Client([
       'base_uri' => 'https://www.space-track.org',
       'timeout'  => 2.0,
   ]);
```

I access the JSON file using:

```
    $response = $client->request('GET', '/basicspacedata/query/class/boxscore');
```

In order to get the JSON file I am required to login to the API. The API tutorial tells me:

```
 Login by sending a HTTP POST request ('identity=your_username&password=your_password') to: https://www.space-track.org/ajaxauth/login
```

What I am unable to do is login to the API using Guzzle. I tried following a few Guzzle tutorials and using the 'auth' array to which none worked.

Basically, what I am unable to do is to login to the API using Guzzle.

Comment: Why not just post the login parameters like `$client->post('https://www.space-track.org/ajaxauth/login?identity=your_username&password=your_password')`, then get token or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic flow that should work

```php
// Initialize the client
$api = new Client([
    'base_uri' => 'https://www.space-track.org',
    'cookies' => true, // You have to have cookies turned on for this API to work
]);

// Login
$api->post('ajaxauth/login', [
    'form_params' => [
        'identity' => '<username>', // use your actual username
        'password' => '<password>', // use your actual password
    ],
]);

// Fetch
$response = $api->get('basicspacedata/query/class/boxscore/format/json');
// and decode some data
$boxscore = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());

// And logout
$api->get('ajaxauth/logout');

dd($boxscore);
```

Now if it's not a one off request and you're planing on extensively using this API you can wrap this "ugliness" in your own service class that exposes a meaningful internal API that allows you to write then something along the lines of

```php
$spaceTrack = new App\Services\SpaceTrack\Client();
$boxscore = $spaceTrack->getBoxscore();
dd($boxscore);
```